# How reorder layers in animation? (grease pencil)

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, layers

please tell me how to change the order of layers in the animation?

I want the blue ball to hide behind the red during the animation.
But in order not to create additional layers with a blue ball

buttons to move the layer can not be animated?

[image]

Comment: I've been researching a lot about it and I couldn't get an exact solution, so I decided to duplicate the layers that I needed to overlay and associate their opacity to bones through drivers. The result is satisfactory in [30 seconds of this video](https://youtu.be/lEx50M2MVW8) and this [simplified process](https://youtu.be/SY1WqKVsMys).

Answer (score 1):

Use the up and down triangles on the right side of the window to reorder the elements.
[image]

Comment: I'm talking about something else. I know how to change the order of the layers, but I want the switching to happen in the animation

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this, not including the one you have.

The first is separating each ball onto its own object, then translating the objects’ Y axis to literally move one ball behind the other. Grease pencil objects are flat, so a translation as small as 0.001 should suffice. This method is good if you have a lot of individual objects with their own properties because you can then parent them, like pieces of armor or orbiting planets.

The other method is the ‘switchboard’ technique, which utilizes the dope sheet. At a certain point in the animation, copy layer 1’s keyframe and paste it onto layer 2, then copy layer 2’s key frame onto layer 1 - manually switching the two. This is good if you have a lot of components to a single object, say like fingers on a hand.

Comment: Could you explain your second method in more detail? What exact keyframe is being copied from Layer 1 to Layer 2? What actual channel is this keyframe being set for? This matters, because if we set the keyframe on the wrong channel, we won't get the desired results. I also ask because I don't know of any channel that, when keyed, would allow for the apparent order of two grease pencil layers to be reversed. But I'd like to know.

Comment: The switchboard technique doesn’t do anything to reverse the layers themselves. It is literally just copy/pasting the image from one layer onto another via the dope sheet. 

Using your example of the red and blue circles on two different layers, go to the dope sheet and select the top layer’s initial keyframe and Copy it. Then go to a later frame with the bottom layer selected and Paste it. Afterward, do the same with the bottom layer’s initial keyframe, effectively switching the two. This process does not use the layer menu whatsoever - only the dope sheet.

Comment: Thank you. That is clear. It was also educational. I would have never thought to try this. In fact, I still wasn't sure I believed what you were saying would work until I tested it out myself. Even after testing, I was initially unsure that it was working. But it does indeed work, done exactly like you said. Though it still isn't quite clear to me WHY it works. Still, it's probably the easiest way to change the apparent order of two grease pencil layers.

Comment: After testing this a second time, my understanding of how it works has improved. Apparently, when you copy and paste the keyframes to different layers, you are transferring the contents as they existed at the keyed time to the new layer. You aren't changing the layer order, just as you pointed out. Instead, you're transferring the actual contents, via keyframe. This makes sense to me now. Still, it would be nice if grease pencil layer visibility was a keyframable property.